# xml with multiple data processing in django spyne

Tags: xml, django, web-services, spyne

i have a server running django and spyne,
i want to configure spyne to accept xml like below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:loc="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/send/v4_0/local">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>

<loc:sendSms>
<loc:addresses>[addresses]</loc:addresses>
<loc:senderName>[senderName]</loc:senderName>
<loc:message>[message]</loc:message>
<loc:receiptRequest>
    <endpoint></endpoint>
    <interfaceName></interfaceName>
    <correlator></correlator>
</loc:receiptRequest>
</loc:sendSms>

<loc:sendSms>
<loc:addresses>[addresses]</loc:addresses>
<loc:senderName>[senderName]</loc:senderName>
<loc:message>[message]</loc:message>
<loc:receiptRequest>
    <endpoint></endpoint>
    <interfaceName></interfaceName>
    <correlator></correlator>
</loc:receiptRequest>
</loc:sendSms>

.
.
.

</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

is it possible?
how should i do so?

and changing the client is impossible, so i have to work with this format.

**EDIT:**

what i have done till now:

model:

```
class ReceiptRequestItem(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = 'http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/send/v4_0/local'
    endpoint = Unicode()
    interfaceName = Unicode()
    correlator = Unicode()
```

service:

```
class MOMessageService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(Unicode, Unicode, Unicode, ReceiptRequestItem,
         _returns=Unicode,
         _in_variable_names={'sender_name': 'senderName',
                             'receipt_request': 'receiptRequest'},
         _operation_name='sendSms')
    def send_sms(ctx, addresses, sender_name, message, receipt_request):
         print addresses, sender_name, message, receipt_request
         return
```

application:

```
mo_message_app = Application([MOMessageService],
                             'http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/send/v4_0/local',
                             in_protocol=Soap11(validator='soft'),
                             out_protocol=Soap11(), )

mo_message_service = csrf_exempt(DjangoApplication(mo_message_app))
```

this works when there is just one

```
<loc:sendSms>
```

though there is a problem with namespaces and lxml validator will result in error.

the question is how to change the code to accept multiple tags.

P.S: also i will be grateful if someone tell me how to fix my problem with namespaces. :)

**EDIT2:**

this is the error I encounter while using lxml validator:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<senv:Envelope xmlns:senv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <senv:Body>
        <senv:Fault>
            <faultcode>senv:Client.SchemaValidationError</faultcode>
            <faultstring>:1:0:ERROR:SCHEMASV:SCHEMAV_ELEMENT_CONTENT: Element 'endpoint': This element is not expected.
                Expected is one of ( {http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/send/v4_0/local}endpoint,
                {http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/send/v4_0/local}interfaceName,
                {http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/send/v4_0/local}correlator ).
            </faultstring>
            <faultactor></faultactor>
        </senv:Fault>
    </senv:Body>
</senv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You need to show some code first, though.

Comment: @BurakArslan i have edited my question. thank you in advance.

Comment: First, Spyne does not support multiple tags under the body element. Patches are welcome.

Comment: As for the lxml validation failing, please also post the server-side traceback you're getting so I can comment on that..

Comment: @BurakArslan thank you, i am not sure if you mean that but i have added my error response.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this syntax when defining your `ComplexModel`s to be accessed by foreign (non-python) systems.

```
class ReceiptRequestItem(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = 'http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/sms/send/v4_0/local'
    _type_info = [
        ('endpoint', Unicode)
        ('interfaceName', Unicode)
        ('correlator', Unicode)
    ]
```

See:

https://github.com/arskom/spyne/pull/313

https://github.com/arskom/spyne/pull/343